# OR condition in CSS selector

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

I'm trying to find an element by a CSS selector. I have a script which I'm using on multiple sites, and there is the same element, but with different classes. Is there any way to find by something like that:

```
css=div[(id='resultVersionA']||[id='resultVersionB')]
```

It must work for my next elements

```
#first-order price, #first price input[type='submit']
```

To be more clear: In upon query I want to select button which is under div which is I 'first_order price' OR  'first price'.

Comment: `#resultVersionA, #resultVersionB { ... }` do you mean this?

Comment: You want to apply CSS to **both** of these elements? Or just one of them? What if both are present in the same page?

Comment: at one site there is only element with one of these id

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#first-order price input[type='submit'], #first price input[type='submit']
```

Comment: thx for help :) but for real my elements have ids like 'first-order price' or 'user name'. I'm not a maker of this ids. I'm only trying to automate this site :/ . Could you give me query for this example?

Answer (score 0):

```
#first-order price, #first price input[type='submit']
```

Answer (score -1):

Do both elements have different IDs as well as classes? If they have different IDs you could just use:

```
document.GetElementById('resultVersionA');
```

Otherwise, if this element is only used once on the page with a given class, then:

```
var rsltVerA = document.GetElementsByTagName('div').getClass('resultVersionA');

var rsltVerB = document.GetElementsByTagName('div').getClass('resultVersionB');
```